# Text Extraction using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, text, extract

I need to extract text from articles online for an ios app I am developping.  Is there something similar to [goose](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) that extracts just the article from the html for Swift?

Answer (score 3):

It's very interesting subject. I'm not pretty sure, but it seems to be not an easy job to do. Recently Ivan Titov told about "Inducing Semantic Representations from Text with Little or No Supervision." You can see this presentation here: https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/2728/ (in English.)

So, our team recently took part in Swift-hackathon by CocoaHeads Moscow for this subject, but not very good result were earned. We developed recursive grabber and other cool things, but can't attain the goal. If you want to contribute to that project, look at this repo: https://github.com/CocoaHeadsMsk/hawking